# quickest way to check if a user exists in an active directory group in c#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am writing a method to determine if a user exists in an Active Directory Group. I may not know this user's password but I do have another username/password in this Active Directory Group. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Setting the SamAccountName property and the call to userFound.GetGroups() seems to be bottlenecks.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
try
{
  using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ipaddress, remoteDomainAndUserName, password))
  {
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(pc);
    try
    {
      qbeUser.SamAccountName = lookUpUserName; // don't know password of this user
      aDResult = ADResult.Valid; // right now remoteDomainAndUserName/password is valid on the domain, don't know if lookUpUserName is a valid user yet
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      return ADResult.InvalidNonLookupID;
    }

    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
    {
      UserPrincipal userFound = found as UserPrincipal;

      if (userFound != null)
      {
        foreach (Principal p in userFound.GetGroups())
        {
          if (p.SamAccountName.ToLower().Trim() == groupName)
          {
            bool isEnabled = true;
            if (userFound.Enabled.HasValue)
            {
              isEnabled = userFound.Enabled.Value;
            }
            if (isEnabled)
              return ADResult.ValidInGroup;
            else
              return ADResult.DisabledInGroup;
          }
          else
            aDResult = ADResult.InvalidInGroup;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
catch (PrincipalServerDownException e)
{
            // cannot connect to AD
            aDResult = ADResult.Offline;
}
catch (LdapException e)
{
            // cannot connect to AD
            aDResult = ADResult.Offline;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
            // cannot connect to AD
            aDResult = ADResult.Offline;
}
```

Comment: I added a method below which I use for seeing if a user is a member of an AD group which I use in a WCF web service. The line group.Members.Contains(user) is the key, this is so much faster than searching through each group a user belongs to, instead we just check the specific group for the user.

Comment: The most efficient way is to check user tokenGroups attribute, as it contains all security groups that user belongs to.

Comment: The attribute is constructed returns you the entire user membership including nested groups. However, you have to bind to the user directly to get those groups and the attribute does not contain local groups from other domain in forest. For example, you need to check, if user from domain A belongs to a local group from child  domain A.B. Bind to a global catalog from domain A.B and query tokenGroups.

Answer (score 1):

```
//This is a method I use in a WCF web service I created
//userName is the sAMAccount name of the user
//groupName is the AD group 
public bool IsMemberOfGroup(string groupName, string userName)
{
            try
            {
                PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName);

                GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName);

                if (group == null)
                    return false;

                if (user != null)
                    return group.Members.Contains(user);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
            }


            return false;
}
```